# validate form before submition

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to submit a form with php variables to input into javascript, the problem is that the variables are only set after posting, which is too late for them to be echoed into the javascript. Of course, if I then submit again, the variables have been implemented into the javascript and it works as it should. However, I would prefer just to submit once.
Is there any way to validate the form before submission ? Here is an example of my dilemma:

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$name=$_POST['name'];}
?>

<html>
 <div id="message"></div>
    <form action="home.html" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="name">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="conditions-met" 
              onclick=<?php if($name=="bob"){echo"start();";}?>>
    </form>
</html>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  function start(){
       document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'hello bob';
  return true;
}
 </script>
```

Comment: php does not suits your needs, JavaScript will work for you, try to use javascript instead these double submission

Comment: check this link for example http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/ajax-validation.php

Comment: You can easily validate the form via Jquery-Ajax

Comment: The main problem is your concept of how PHP and Javascript work and co-work. You need to understand that PHP runs on the server while Javascript runs on the client side (meaning the browser). This means that you need to send a request to the server in order to interact with PHP (either a normal request or an asynchronous request). In your case I don't see how PHP comes into it at all. You don't need any server interaction for what you want to do. Just stay with JS, don't post the form to the server.

Comment: If JS is turned off, it may all get submitted anyway, so you still have to have a robust PHP backend validation process.  Whether from a usability POV you want to return the form with hints will be down to you and the relationship you have with potential users, cost of user loss etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<div id="message"></div>
<form action="home.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="conditions-met" >
</form>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validate(){

name=document.getElementById('name').value;
if(name == "")
{
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Please Fill Name';
return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Man people are mean to you!!

Basically you should validate the fields using JavaScript.

When the submit button is clicked do the checks. Continue on success, show an error message on failure.

example

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return ValidateFields(this)" name="myForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"" action="myPhpScript.php" method="POST">

// html fields


</form>


<script>

function ValidateFields(formObject)
{

   var FieldsValid = true;

   //Validate the fields and if one of them is not valid set FieldsValid to false

if(!FieldsValid )
{
   //show an error message

return false; // Returing false will prevent the form from submitting

}

return true;// the form will be submitted
}

</script>
```

In order to become a ninja please read the following:

http://www.script-tutorials.com/form-validation-with-javascript-and-php/

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/dom-scripting/validate-forms-javascript.shtml

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Answer (score 1):

The function bound to the onclick-event must return true if validation is correct, or false otherwise.

The same function must be in javascript. You cannot call a php function in it. If you want php, try ajax.

```
<input type="submit" onsubmit="return validate();" />

<script>
    function validate() {
        // do validation in javascript
        // or make an ajax request e.g. to 
        //  /validate.php?name=somename&surname=someothername 
        // and let this request answer with true or false

        // return true if valid, otherwise false
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Ajax and *beforeSubmit* function with Jquery You have:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "your async page in php",
            cache: true,
            data: $("#formID").serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(){ 
                         /* You can validate your input here*/
            },
            success: function(response){
                /* Based on the response from php you can handle the message to the user*/
            },
            error: function(response){/*Error Handler*/},
            complete: function(){/*If it's complete than you can reset the form*/}
        });
```

I think it's easy and more clear if you use cross Ajax/PHP request